# What does ?? ternary operator mean using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have code like below,

```
const output = (data?.item?.someItem?.count ?? 0) === 0;
```

what is the value of output in this case what does ?? in above line mean. could someone help me understand this line of code.

I am new to programming. thanks.

Comment: Documentation link: [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: This has nothing to do with react.

Comment: Note that `??` is not a ternary operator. It's a binary operator - it has two operands. "Ternary" just means "has three operands".

Comment: This page gives you a live explanation on each JS operator: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/operator-lookup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as already pointed out, this isn't specific to React, but plain JavaScript syntax.

Let's break it down.

#### Optional Chaining ?.

```js
const result1 = data?.item?.someItem?.count
```

> The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

So even if `data`, `item` or `someItem` is undefined or null, you could still use this statement without generating an error, but you would simply get an `undefined` value.

Read more about it in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

#### Nullish coalescing operator (??)

```js
const result2 = result1 ?? 0
```

As described in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

> The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

In your case, the expression will return `0` if `element` is null or undefined, otherwise it returns `element`.

#### Final output: Strict Equality Comparison

```js
const output = result2 === 0
```

The expression evaluates to true if `result2` is strictly equal to the numeric value `0`. Also read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Answer (score 5):

The "optional chaining operator" `?.` gets a property of an object, if that exists and the "nullish coalescing operator" `??` acts very similar to the `||` operator: It returns the first operand if it is NOT `null` or `undefined` , otherwise it returns the second one.

The `||` behaves *slightly* differently: It will return the seond operand if the first operand is "falsey" (i. e. `0` or `false` will also trigger the second operand to be returned).

You can find more details here: [MDM Web Docs - Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Comment: The other way around for `??` I think?

Comment: Of course - ‍♂️ - got it mixed up when I was writing! Corrected the post accordingly.